# User not found when adding an AD group to an SP group

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to run the code suggested here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72431/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-an-ad-group-to-an-sp-group-with-permissions

The EnsureUser line works, but on the web.Users line, it says user not found.

```
var membersGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName(string.Concat(web.Title, " ", "Members"));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xlosgroupname))
{
    string xlosgroupnamewithdomain = string.Concat(domainName, @"\", xlosgroupname);
    web.EnsureUser(xlosgroupnamewithdomain);
    var adLosGroup = web.Users[xlosgroupnamewithdomain];
    membersGroup.Users.Add(adLosGroup.LoginName, string.Empty, adLosGroup.Name, adLosGroup.Notes);
    SPRoleDefinition contribute = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
    SPRoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = web.RoleAssignments;
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(xlosgroupnamewithdomain, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
    SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefBindings = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;
    roleDefBindings.Add(contribute);
    roleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get all users from the web you specified using the following method:
web.AllUsers

Wish that can help you.